# Real-Valued Error Function on SO(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, control-theory, nonlinear-system, geometric-measure-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

In some geometric control papers, the author usually defines the real-valued error function to be:

$\Psi(R,R_d)$ = $\frac{1}{2} Trace[I - R_d^T R ]$.   (1)

where $R_d$ is the arbitrary smooth attitude tracking command.

My question is what is the physical meaning of Eq.(1).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Up to scaling, for orthogonal matrices that matches the distance between $R$ and $R_d$ induced by the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @coiso, thank you for your comment.  Yes, I agree with your point that it expresses the distance between the R and $R_d$ with the Frobenius norm.  Is it enough to use $Trace(R_d^T R)$ to express the distance between those two matrices?  Why the $Trace(I - R_d^T R)$ should be used?

Comment: ${\rm tr}(R^T_dR)$ would be the Frobenius inner product between $R_d$ and $R$, not the distance between them. The closer $R_d$ and $R$ are, the larger their inner product will be (with max value equal to the dimension). You say you agree with my point; did you verify $\|R-R_d\|_F^2=2{\rm tr}(I-R_d^TR)$?

Comment: @coiso, thank you for your reminder, I did the derivation of $\Vert R - R_d \Vert^2_F$. Yes , I got the result of $2 tr(I - R_d^TR)$. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some physical intuition behind the formula. Set $M = R_d^\top R$. By Rodrigues's Rotation Formula, there exists a unit vector $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and angle $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ so that,

$$M = I_{3\times 3} + (\sin\theta)\,S(a) + (1 - \cos\theta)\,S(a)^2$$

where $S(a)\in\mathrm{Skew}(3)$ is the skew symmetric matrix constructed from the vector $a.$ This is just the axis-angle representation of the error rotation $M.$ The angle $\theta$ essentially is an angular error. Verify that,

$$\mathrm{Trace}(I_{3\times 3} - M)
=
-(\sin\theta)\mathrm{Trace}(S(a)) - (1 - \cos\theta) \mathrm{Trace}(S(a)^2).$$

The trace of a skew symmetric matrix is zero so,

$$\mathrm{Trace}(I_{3\times 3} - M)
=
-(1 - \cos\theta) \mathrm{Trace}(S(a)^2).$$

I'll implore you to do the computation to verify that, using $\|a\|=1,$ $\mathrm{Trace}(S(a)^2)=-2.$ Deduce from this that,

$$\mathrm{Trace}(I_{3\times 3} - M)
=
2\left(1 - \cos(\theta)\right).$$

Therefore the expression

$$\frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{Trace}(I_{3\times 3} - R_d^\top R)
=
1 - \cos(\theta)
=
2\,\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right).
$$

is really just a measure of positive angular deviation from the current orientation to the desired orientation.

Comment: Dear Rollen, thank you for your help. It really helpful.